# I am getting the vscode error: "The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error". How do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, visual-studio-code, github-codespaces

Basically I am making a discord bot on github codespaces (online vscode), and it was working for a while, but after I closed out of my tab, and re-opened it, it is giving me this error:

[image: This is the picture of the error].

I don't know what is causing this error. I tried creating a new codespace for the repo, but it still has the same issue. I created a new repository with a codespace to see if I got the same error. It again worked at first, but then came up with the same error. Can someone tell me what is happening, and how to fix it? The git tab (source control) also says `No source control providers registered`. Sometimes, the run button (looks like play button), doesn't show up. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it isn't an issue with the code, it is an issue with visual studio code on startup.

Comment: Please describe your error in detail. Your operation steps and problems encountered, etc., can help you solve the problem better if people can reproduce your problem.

Comment: That's not an error about VS Code itself, but about your use of it: it's pretty clearly telling you that you have a tab open for a file that doesn't exist/cannot be reached, so just close the tab, and open the real file instead.

Answer (score -1):

Use vscode [client](https://code.visualstudio.com/). Check if the file path exists. Follow this [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/vscode-web).

Comment: I didn't created the file locally. I created a GitHub repo, and then opened a GitHub Codespace within that repo.

Answer (score -1):

For me I just had to remove the folder from the workspace, and re-add it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).